# Can't connect to Oracle database from application

Tags: oracle, jdbc

after restarting operating system (aix) I am not able to connect to locally installed oracle db from my application.

connected to sqlplus and executed startup command.

Select statements working fine from sqlplus. Should we start listener separately?

But the application fails with:

```
Error:
IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150916-55dc7c3): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
```

Comment: If you haven't started the listener then yes, you have to start that (`lsnrctl status` to see if it's running, `lsnrctl start` if it isn't). You can automate that on server startup, of course. (It's also possible, though unlikely, that your server is getting its IP address via DHCP and has a different address now; and if 'local' means you're using localhost to connect then that doesn't apply anyway).

Comment: Listner.ora got corrupted. replaced the old one and it worked.